# Optional Insurance Option for Cart

Tags: cart, shipping, shipping-methods

I want to create an option for my customer that they can select for insurance that will cost 65 cents for every 100$ they spend for the entire order.

Keep in mind I only want to give the option to insure everything not individual items.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that could better be implemented as a **custom total** than as a separate product.

I won't go into detail with how to do that, you will find tutorials such as http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

The `collect` method can add the insurance fee based on the subtotal.

So far it is pretty standard. But you want the customer to choose if they want insurance or not. I would implement this similar to discount codes:

- new quote attribute "has_insurance"
- a form on the cart page
- a custom controller for this form that sets the new attribute, then redirects back to the cart
- in the custom total, only add the insurance fee if `has_insurance=1`

Note that on every page load on the cart, the totals are recalculated without further ado.